# ffmpeg how do I choose the correct Audio track?

Tags: ffmpeg, converters, mkv

I'm converting a few .mkv files and need to choose the right Audio track, but dont know how.

This is the command I use:

```
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

It is recommended by the webservice where I want to upload the video.

Let's say the Audiotracks look like this:

```
mkvmerge -i "movie.mkv"

Track ID 0: video (MPEG-4p10/AVC/h.264)
Track ID 1: audio (AC-3)
Track ID 2: audio (TrueHD)
Track ID 3: subtitles (HDMV PGS)
```

How do I select "Track 1" or "Track 2" for Output?
And which track will be selected, if I leave the Code like that? (and why?)

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ffmpeg has the [-map](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options) option for manually selecting streams.

For the file shown, use

```
ffmpeg -i "movie.mkv" -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:1 -vcodec h264 -acodec aac -strict -2 output.mp4
```

`-strict -2` isn't required for your command with ffmpeg builds from 2016 or later.